# batch script to copy from external PC

Tags: command-line, usb, batch

I'm trying to write a batch script for copying appdata files to my usb drive...i figured (which i'm not sure about) that if in any pc i plugin my usb %appdata% can be used as default path but for every pc drive letter for usb changes so what would be the best way to assign such a path which directly co-responds to usb??
the command i'm using for copy is xcopy with parameters /y /s

Comment: Pass the USB drive letter as a parameter when you run the batch file and use that value inside the batch file. See [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your assumed destination is the folder holding your command file.
The following simply tell it where to get stuff from.

copy %appdata%*.*

or

copy c:\download

if your batch is in usb X:\123 = this is where the copies files will go.

Answer (score 1):

If you store the CMD file on the USB drive and run it from there, then you can use the working directory of the script to help you out.

*Contents of CopyAppdataHere.cmd:*

```
xcopy /y /s %appdata% %~dp0SomeFolder
```

In the script, `%~dp0` expands to the drive and the path of the CMD file (including the trailing backslash), even if it's not the active current directory, and will put the files in the *SomeFolder* directory.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of methods. The first method which would be easiest would be:

```
if exist=D:\Data\Teat.TXT goto :copy
```

Just run down the tree until it finds the letter assigned to your USB.

Another method would be at the start of your Batch have a menu option where you input the letter of the USB and assign it a variable, this will then be used in the script where called upon.

Lastly if you're running the `*.bat` from the USB you should be able to reference the device path, I can follow up on this if you want.